# C# fileinfo class lastwritetime property

Tags: c#, fileinfo

```
Byte[] mtime = new Byte[4];
mtime = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
fs.Write(mtime, 0, mtime.Length);
```

The code is stored as a binary file like "2016-01-15 ?? 5:45:11" <--

I want to know if 'Lastwritetime' have certain properties.

only get date. like "20160115"

Comment: Are you saying that you just want the _date_ and **not** the _time_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the date part in that format, use:

`file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)